# Formula using both MIN and MAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The goal is to have an equation calculate a gross amount including overtime. The issue I am having is the results will not exceed my first statement of 700.

```
=(MIN(B6*D6,700))+(MAX(B6-40*(D6*1.5),0))
```

wheras B6 = Hours and D6 = Wage

My understanding of this should multiply no more than 40 hours by the wage (hence the 700 cap) and to add no less than 0 hours by the wage and a half. What am I missing?

Comment: put `()` around the `(B6-40)` otherwise it multiplies the 40 with (D6*1.5) before subtractine from B6.

Comment: Wow, such a rookie mistake. Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to split hours into regular hours and overtime hours, with regular hours defined as the first 40 and overtime hours as anything above this then `MIN(B6,40)` gives the regular hours and `MAX(B6-40,0)` gives the overtime. Each can be then be multiplied by the appropriate wage rate. The 700 cap could effectively be capping the wage rate payable for regular time eg if B6 is 40, the regular wage rate will effectively be capped at 17.5. If B6 is 50 it is capped at 14.0 but the overtime rate for the additional 10 hours is not similarly capped. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, I have fixed that!